# How to find age of kelp in minecraft bedrock

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing minecraft bedrock in mobile. I'm gonna make a kelp farm. I need to find the age of kelp in bedrock edition. It will be in debug screen for java, but how can I do it in bedrock? Please help me.

Comment: I'm not sure how finding the age of individual plants would help you. Kelp will grow the same random 2 to 26 blocks as on Java, which gets re-randomized after each harvest. That means your farm should be able to deal with every possible value and in case you have uneven sea bottom to deal with, you can just build up any plants (by placing kelp manually on top of the plant) to get them within reach of the harvester if that's your farm design.

Comment: Thanks I thought it won't change after harvesting

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you can't find out the age of kelp in bedrock because bedrock doesn't have the debug screen.

Comment: I do not play Bedrock edition, but I do think this answer is correct. Debug screens in mobile are very rare, mostly because there is not a lot of inputs that can be put in. So except if someone can show this answer wrong by giving a way to open a debug screen on mobile, this answer is, IMO, valid.